# Reference typescript definitions in one file, instead of all JS files?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a Node JS (+Express) project in Visual Studio Code, and am wondering if there is a way to reference TypeScript definitions in one global spot, rather than having to re-reference definitions in every JS file.

I see that VSCode supports tsconfigs, but I don't think .tsconfig files have a section for that.

Comment: Generally external tools which only use `tsc` require that you include a reference at the top of every file. Visual Studio has a feature which does this automatically, but I'm not sure if this is included in "Code"

Comment: see answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40861142/187650

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In some editors you can use the `filesGlob` property in tsconfig.json to simplify references.

For example:

```
"filesGlob": [
    "./scripts/*.ts",
    "!./node_modules/**/*.ts"
]
```

However, this will work with the TypeScript compiler only when TypeScript 2 is released (see [globs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#20)):

Or you can specify individual `files`:

```
"files": [
    "./scripts/app.ts",
    "./scripts/other.d.ts"
]
```

Comment: I did **not** know about this. I need to put this into IntelliJ *right now*. Thanks!

Comment: It appears Visual Studio Code does support a tsconfig.json file. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/04/30/using-typescript-in-visual-studio-code.aspx

Comment: Yes - but not filesGlob yet, so you have to specify files instead.

Comment: if you leave files undefined (or omit it) then all files are included. much easier if you want them all, until globs are included

Answer (score 1):

Okay so after a couple of restarts with Code, it seems that most of the time it will pick up the typescript definitions that you've included in other files.

I think I'll still go with Steve's answer though, as that way I can avoid having a bunch of references in my code.