# Typescript : register modules and avoid the use of the `reference` tag

Tags: javascript, typescript, systemjs

I'm working on a project using :

- Angular 2
- TypeScript (transpiled to es5 obviously)
- SystemJS

I'm new to TS.

I've built a module loader that lets me code and manage some modules easily. Using this system, I can load modules using `import` :

`import {something} from 'namespace@myModule';`

I can do this thanks to SystemJS. My modules are registered to SystemJS (using `map` and `package`). But the TypeScript compiler doesn't know anything about those modules. So when I run my shiny `npm start` and when the compiler starts, a lot of errors are throwned.

I would like to "register" those modules to avoid this side-effect.

As far as I know, I don't need `.d.ts` because my modules are written directly in TypeScript.
I've read some things about `///<reference>` and I don't really like it.

The advantage of my little module loader is that I can directly use module inside another. I just need to `import` it no matter where it is located etc. With `///<reference>`, I'll need to also give a relative path and this isn't my goal.

It would be very cool if I would be able to :

```
// configure a "path" in tsconfig.json
"aliases": {
  "/path/to/modules/folder": "modules" // <--- path:alias
}

// and in another file importing a module
/// <reference path="modules/namespace@myModule" /> 
import {something} form 'namespace@myModule';

//...
```

Thanks !

Comment: Maybe [this article](http://blog.johnnyreilly.com/2015/02/hey-tsconfigjson-where-have-you-been.html) can help you

Comment: This article is really usefull. Thanks a lot. Unfortunately I'm using Webstorm. Switch to Atom and be able to use `filesGlob` can be a solution, but I would like to dig a bit more before changing my dev env :). (I've just found this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1927))

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **@DragonRock**, [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29975553/5542588) and this [roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#20), this would seem to be impossible.

Right now.

As you can see on the typescript's roadmap, the version *2.0* will provides `globs` (see [this issue, again !](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1927)).
We will be able to add static files in our `tsconfig.json` instead for `<reference>`-ing them in our `.ts` files.

As **@DragonRock**'s article says, some editors already provide this feature like [Atom](https://atom.io/).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: AFAIK, the `_references.ts` file does exactly that, you can list files to be globally referenced.