# gulp-typescript emitting errors upon save, but is fine with subsequent saves

Tags: typescript, gulp, angular

I'm not really sure if this is a gulp issue, a typescript issue or an Angular 2 issue.

I am using Angular 2 Beta 6 currently.

This is my typescript gulp task.

```
var tsProject = p.typescript.createProject("tsconfig.json");

gulp.task("client-scripts", function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.client.root + "**/*.ts")
        .pipe(p.cached("client-scripts"))
        .pipe(p.typescript(tsProject))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.webroot.root));
});
```

And this is my tsconfig file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

My Angular 2 bootstrap file, which includes some typings that are required for beta 6 of angular. I think this is one area where the problem could be happening.

```
///<reference path="../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
///<reference path="../../typings/shim.d.ts"/>

import { bootstrap } from "angular2/platform/browser";
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from "angular2/router";
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from "angular2/http";
import { DataPlatformComponent } from "./dataPlatform.component";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";

bootstrap(DataPlatformComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

That shim file only contains a declaration of a module variable, as a workaround to an issue in angular 6 with the module property on the `@component` decorator. I don't know if it might be a reason, but those references at the top are only on the boot.ts file and not any other subsequent ts file I am saving.

Upon initial run of my gulp build process everything is peachy...

```
[08:41:28] Starting 'entry'...
[08:41:28] Starting 'cleanup'...
[08:41:28] Finished 'entry' after 2.82 ms
[08:41:28] Finished 'cleanup' after 74 ms
[08:41:28] Starting 'initialize'...
[08:41:28] Starting 'vendor-scripts'...
[08:41:28] Starting 'vendor-content'...
[08:41:28] Starting 'client-scripts'...
[08:41:28] Starting 'client-nonscripts'...
[08:41:28] Starting 'client-sass'...
[08:41:28] Finished 'initialize' after 21 ms
[08:41:28] Finished 'vendor-scripts' after 176 ms
[08:41:28] Finished 'vendor-content' after 185 ms
[08:41:28] Finished 'client-sass' after 235 ms
[08:41:30] Finished 'client-scripts' after 2.31 s
[08:41:30] Finished 'client-nonscripts' after 2.3 s
```

But if I go into one of my typescript files, and make a valid change or just a whitespace change like from this...

```
export class DataPlatformComponent {
}
```

to this

```
export class DataPlatformComponent {

}
```

I get a huge list of errors in my gulp output window. The two following lists are only snippets.

```
[08:59:08] Starting 'client-scripts'...
C:/Github/Data-Platform/src/DataPlatform/client/platform/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts(4,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.
client\platform\dataplatform.component.ts(8,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.
[08:59:10] TypeScript: 62 semantic errors
C:/Github/Data-Platform/src/DataPlatform/client/platform/report catalog/details/chip.component.ts(6,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.
C:/Github/Data-Platform/src/DataPlatform/client/platform/report catalog/details/reportDetails.component.ts(7,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.
[08:59:10] TypeScript: emit failed
C:/Github/Data-Platform/src/DataPlatform/client/platform/report catalog/main/navigation.component.ts(8,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.
```

Mostly those module error complaints and rxjs complaints.

```
[08:59:10] Finished 'client-scripts' after 2.08 s
C:/Github/Data-Platform/src/DataPlatform/client/platform/shell/navigation.component.ts(7,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.
C:/Github/Data-Platform/src/DataPlatform/node_modules/angular2/src/core/change_detection/parser/locals.d.ts(3,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/Github/Data-Platform/src/DataPlatform/node_modules/angular2/src/core/change_detection/parser/locals.d.ts(4,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/Github/Data-Platform/src/DataPlatform/node_modules/angular2/src/core/debug/debug_node.d.ts(14,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/Github/Data-Platform/src/DataPlatform/node_modules/angular2/src/core/debug/debug_node.d.ts(24,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
```

If I save the file again, things are fine... but it seems to have interrupted my file emits, and so I have to restart the entire build process.

```
[09:02:50] Starting 'client-scripts'...
[09:02:51] Finished 'client-scripts' after 1.28 s
```

As requested, here is my directory structure... with most of the files I think are unnecessary omitted.

```
|-DataPlatform
    |-wwwroot
    |-client
        |-platform
            |-content
            |-dashboard
            |-report catalog
            |-shared
            |-shell
            boot.ts
            dataPlatform.component.ts
            dataPlatform.template.html
        index.html
    |-node_modules
    |-typings
        shim.d.ts
    gulpfile.js
    package.json
    project.json
    tsconfig.json
    Startup.cs
```

Comment: Can you check what version of typescript you're using? Is it the latest `gulp-typescript`?

Comment: It was "gulp-typescript": "2.10.0", with typescript 1.7.5. I've just updated to gulp-typescript of 2.11.0 and typescript of 1.8.2 and the problem is still persisting.

Comment: Could you also post your directory structure?

Comment: Please see the edit at the bottom.

Comment: Everything looks fine, btw what's your `npm` version? If it's < 3.0 try upgrading, then remove `node_modules` directory and install it again. Since version 3.0 it tries to install dependencies flat so it might be related to this.

Comment: So... I had an older version. Multiple versions in fact. My system path variables had multiple entries, so it was defaulting to an older version. Moreover, Visual Studio was using its own version. I have since remedied all of that so I'm using the latest node version, and reinstalled the node_modules directory. The issue persists, tragically. Could it be some sort of issue with the module system? Why does it build fine initially, but fail upon a change, then build fine again after retrying?

Answer (score 6):

Add

```
/// <reference path="node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts" />
```

in the main TS file.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7280#issuecomment-188777966

Comment: See I've done this. It works for the main TS file but all subsequent files continue to throw errors upon making a change... i'd have to add that reference to every single TS file for it to work.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989399/do-i-have-to-reference-typescript-definition-in-every-file