# Using the typeahead.js definitely typed file

Tags: typeahead.js, typescript2.0

I just downloaded the [typeahead.js d.ts](https://www.nuget.org/packages/typeahead.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/) file, but how the hell do you use it ?

The options object has to be written in this format:

```
let a:Twitter.Typeahead.Options = {};
```

But how do I define the source ?

This is causing a compiler error-:

```
let b:Twitter.Typeahead.Dataset<string> = 
{source:{query:'',syncResults:null,asyncResults:null}};
```

Can someone help me with the syntax ?

EDIT:
Solved it:

here is the code I used in typescript-: You need jquery, for $.each() function.

```
private sourceFactory(list: string[]):
        (query: string, syncResults: (results: string[]) => void) => void {
    return (query: string, syncResults: (results: string[]) => void) => {

        let matches: string[] = [];

        let regex: RegExp = new RegExp('^' + query, 'i');

        $.each(list, (i: number, str: string) => {
            if (regex.test(str)) {
                matches.push(str);
            }
        });

        syncResults(matches);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference your file, for example:

```
/// <reference path="Validation.ts" />
```

or

```
/// <reference path="./../Scripts/typings/foo.d.ts" />
```

see: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html

1) put the .d.ts file in your tsconfig.json as described here: [Do I have to reference typescript definition in every file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989399/do-i-have-to-reference-typescript-definition-in-every-file/40861142#40861142)

2) try to call the method via namespace:

```
Twitter.Typeahead.callsomething()
```

or import it like

```
import tah from 'foo'
import { default as tah } from 'foo'
```

you also need to download jquery as this library depends on it (look at the .d.ts file).

Comment: Already did that I am asking on how to write the code. What do I put in `$("#input").typeahead()` ? How do I declare the async and sync sources and also the query strings ?