# TypeScript - Include all files automatically in the right order using tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript2.0, tsc, tsconfig

**EDIT at the bottom of the question - added more info.**

I'm compiling my TypeScript project in Visual Studio Code via Ctrl+Shift+B (uses tsc under the hood as far as I understand), I have a tsconfig.json.

My project has many folders and subfolders with .ts files.

I'd like to include all the .ts files in my project without any reference path tags, and in the right order so that I don't get the error "Class % used before its declaration.".

It seems it is possible and has already been solved before on StackOverflow:

[Do I have to reference typescript definition in every file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989399/do-i-have-to-reference-typescript-definition-in-every-file)

> UPDATE for TypeScript >= v1.5: you can use a tsconfig.json file, and
>   the compiler will get the ordering of the classes right. This removes
>   the need to use gulp-typescript alltogether. You can either chose to
>   have all files explicitly listed in the tsconfig.json file, or
>   completely leave out the files property to include all *.ts/*.tsx
>   files within the directory the tsconfig.json resides (including all
>   subfolders).

However applying their solution doesn't seem to solve it for me, I'm not sure what I'm not doing right.

I removed all the reference path tags from my project, and in my tsconfig.json I tried:

a. Not specifying "files"

b.

```
"files": [
    "*.ts/*.tsx"
]
```

c.

```
"files": [
    "**/"
]
```

which recursively goes over all subfolders according to:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

In all cases I'm getting "Cannot find name %." and "Class % used before its declaration." all over my project.

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "outFile": "../src/app.js"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "lib"
    ]
}
```

What am I not doing right?

Is it really supposed to work automatically or is there something else I need to do?

I'm using the latest TypeScript.

I removed the module parameter in compilerOptions in order to be able to specify a single outFile, perhaps that's the problem?

Maybe if I used a module like commonjs it'd have worked?

Comment: The phrase *completely leave out the files property* means your file should end in `"exclude": [ "lib" ] }`. In other words, there should be no "files" node in your tsconfig.json file at all.

Comment: You are right, but the errors remain even like that.

Comment: Fair enough; just wanted to let you know that you were perhaps interpreting what was said incorrectly. I don't actually know the answer, sorry :).

Comment: You were right, I misinterpreted it. Updated the question, thanks :)

Comment: (Not solved yet)

Comment: You really should use modules. The order of inclusion of global script files will always be a headache.

Comment: Which module should I use in my case? Would it solve my problem or is it just a nice thing to have? Are you sure the order will always be a headache? From the answer I quoted in my question:*UPDATE for TypeScript >= v1.5: you can use a tsconfig.json file, **and the compiler will get the ordering of the classes right.**

Comment: Does anybody have an idea?